# PHP Laravel : TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Here the scenario is, I want to fetch some data from database and show it to user. While someone give some input and save it to database and I put a status with that which is always "`0`" until someone see it. So whenever a input has submitted user will see a pop up screen with that new data has inserted in another page. Here the problem is when ajax got some value with status "`0`" it shown it to screen but when it couldn't fetch any value ( `when all the status value is 1`)it shows error in console :

> `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67`

.

How do I solve the issue , any possible suggestion please ?

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('/unread',[
    'uses'=>'ItemController@getUnread',
    'as'=>'unread'
    ]);

Route::post('/s_update',[
    'uses'=>'ItemController@status_update',
    'as'=>'s_update'
    ]);
```

Here is the controller :

```
public function getUnread()
            {

                $items=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT count(*) as total from items where status =0"));
                // $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($items);
                 return Response::json($items);
            }       

            public function status_update()
            {
                $items=DB::select(DB::raw("UPDATE items SET status=1 WHERE status=0"));
                return Response::json($items);
            }
```

and here is the ajax call :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                    setInterval(function(){ 
                            $(".container").load("list", function(){
                                $.ajaxSetup({
                                  headers: {
                                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                      }
                                 });

                                  $.ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "{{url('unread')}}",                                                             
                                     dataType : 'json',                             
                                    success : function(data) {

                                            $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){                                                              
                                                if(subcatObj.total != '0')
                                                {
                                                    var yes = confirm('You have '+subcatObj.total+' new messages');
                                                            if(yes){
                                                                status_update();
                                                            }
                                                }

                                        });                             
                                    }, 
    });                                                                  
                        });          
                         }, 3000);  

                         function status_update(){

                           $.ajax({  
                                url:"{{url('s_update')}}",  
                                method:"POST",                                                                  
                           });  
                         }          
                </script>
```

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({
                              headers: {
                                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                  }
                             });` is a global setting, you don't need to declare it each time you're using $.ajax

Comment: I removed it though ..still faced same problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this route

```
Route::post('/unread',[
'uses'=>'ItemController@getUnread',
'as'=>'unread'
]);
```

to

```
Route::get('/unread',[
'uses'=>'ItemController@getUnread',
'as'=>'unread'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are not sending the laravel csrf token in the post.

You need to send a field called "_token" in the json which is the csrf_token provided.

See here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: I used it in <head> tag using meta tag 
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: yeah, but try adding it in the actual json content as well. it should be _token, not csrf-token in the json data.

Comment: I changed it to `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')`

But same Error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

> {{ csrf_field() }}

use this to generae csrf token in your form

Comment: there is no form issue ..
Means I haven't used any form here